# Clipped shapefile not appearing on screen using QGIS

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, clip

I have just installed QGIS and I want to clip 1 polygon into the boundaries of another polygon.

This seems like a simple thing to do and I use the clip tool to do so. However, when I click the zoom to layer option on the newly clipped polygon nothing on my screen shows up. All my layers including the new clipped polygon are in the same CRS and I don't understand why the clipped polygon shows up in the layers panel (which I can toggle on and off, but doesn't actually do anything?) but not on the actual screen.

At this point I am thinking this is a bug.

Any ideas how I can fix this bug or alternative things I can do?

Comment: Can you have a look at these functions and confirm that the clip operation is indeed what you are looking to do? https://grindgis.com/software/qgis/basic-editing-tools-in-qgis

Comment: can you share your files so others can try?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Also in general it is worth asking yourself have lots of other people used this tool correctly and had no problem before assuming you have found a bug.

Comment: I have since managed to do what I was wanting to do with a diffrent app. I used ArcGIS which managed to perform this simple task without all the errors and bugs from QGIS. Can defo recommend ArcGIS over the drivel that is QGIS. If you want to find out more about ArcGIS just google it. The website should come up. Thanks everyone for all the helpful, unhelpful comments ;)

Comment: Generally Ian, when something doesn't work when it is supposed to with no clear cut explanation then that is called a bug. You can find out more if you learn about computor programing. Thanks :)